# Display specific row details from database into PDF page in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have an issue, I have retrieved all the details of a row into pdf page but the issue is, when i click it echo's the id in the browser but not the specific id record from database.

On a little change, shows first row from mysql on every id button clicked.

Sometime displays all the record on the PDF page.

**Example:** If one record covers 2 pages of PDF page then it shows like 10 pages of all the rows showing in pdf page.

When I change the sql query like `Select * from students where id = '$id'` then this gives this error.

> (Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login Registration
>   system\admin\includes\pdf\index.php on line 13)

Please help me out .

Its the Button from Where i call the pdf page:

```
<th scope="row"><a href="includes/pdf/index.php?action=select&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="btn btn-success">Print</a></th>
```

Now its the **PDF index page** :

```
<?php
require('library/fpdf.php');
include("pconnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM students ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
  $pdf->Ln();
  $pdf->Ln();

  $pdf->Ln();

  $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 10);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 20, 'Name on Passport', 1, 0);
  $pdf->Cell(60, 10, $rows['firstname'], 1, 0, 'C');

  $pdf->SetX(40);
  $pdf->Cell(60, 10, $rows['lastname'], 1, 0, 'C');

  $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Nationality', 1, 0, 'C');
  $pdf->Cell(45, 10, $rows['nationality'], 1, 0, 'C');

  $pdf->SetX(85);
  $pdf->Cell(28, 10, 'Place of Birth', 1, 0);
  $pdf->Cell(42, 10, $rows['placeofbirth'], 1, 1, 'C');

  $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Date of Birth', 1, 0);
  $pdf->Cell(73, 10, $rows['dateofbirth'], 1, 0, 'C');
  $pdf->Cell(42, 10, $rows['gender'], 1, 0, 'C');

  $pdf->SetY(60);
  $pdf->SetX(155);
  $pdf->Cell(45, 40, $rows['Photo'], 1, 1, 'C');

  $pdf->Output();
}?>
```

Comment: So, what you want. You want records for the specific user in PDF? Right? And, where are you using `action` and `id` in PDF page? What is the use of those arguments

Comment: Yes you are right to get the specific user in pdf. I think that is problem that i am calling action from one page to pdf index but can't write the action. I am confused by what to write. Please help me out in this matter.

Comment: What does `action` do? Means, what role it do in your PDF page? Please elaborate.

Comment: On action should take the id from the database and do two things, one the id should show browser and also the the specific id's user should be printed on pdf page.

Comment: I'm really trying to get around your description. This PDF index page is supposed to show the recored of just the row that is clicked on right?

Comment: Yes it displays one record, but one thing is suppose i have 10 records in database so the button should also be repeated in front of every record fetched from database to index pdf, now the pdf index page shows the first record only from database, if i click on 5 button or 10 button it displays the same first row.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou so much for your comments, I have solved it out by myself. The Issue was i was calling the action but in the index page there was no action.

```
if(($_GET['action'] == 'select') && isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "Select * FROM students WHERE id = '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Ln();
   }
   $pdf->Output();
  }
```